# What's bootstrap.css and why and how is it used

Tags: css

I've seen so many templates having this bootstrap.min.css file which also was like 125kbs. What is it used for?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.
[Link](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: So, why all those tags? I think it's an unnessesary effort. And I've also seen a bootstrap.min.js file too.

Comment: all opniões are valid, but the idea of ​​bootstrap is to reduce the time to create the layout to the schedule.
Formerly the programmer took hours to design a layout with little knowledge , as with bootstrap it gets a good responsive layout quality in a short time .